# An identity for the integral of the $\zeta$ function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

In the study of the free region of zeros of the Riemann $\zeta$ function I'd like to know if this form is correct, where s is the complex variable $s=\sigma+ it$

$\int_{\sigma_1, t_1}^{\sigma_{2},t_2} \zeta'(s) ds = \zeta(\sigma_2,t_2) - \zeta(\sigma_1,t_1)$?

or if t is constant
$\int_{\sigma_1, t}^{\sigma_{2},t} \zeta'(s) ds = \zeta(\sigma_2,t) - \zeta(\sigma_1,t)$?

Comment: If you mean $\int_{\sigma_1+it_1}^{\sigma_{2}+it_2} \zeta'(s)\,\mathrm{ds} = \zeta(\sigma_2+it_2) - \zeta(\sigma_1+it_1)$ then the answer is yes, provided the path of integration doesn't pass through the pole.

Comment: You should look in genneral at $\int_C f'(z)dz = f(b)-f(a)$ for any meromorphic function and any curve $C : a \to b$, for example with $f(z) = e^z$ or $1/z$